# Application crashed when internet is disabled using Loader class in Android?

Tags: android, loader, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I am using LoaderCallBacks in my app and getting data from webservice and saving data in wrapper class if status of data is true i am saving all records in bean class otherwise it returns empty list.The problem is that its bringing data but if i resume application and diconnect internet and again open the app to see the result at that time my app crashed its working fine in case of internet present while failed to show empty list if internet is not connected and sending error **01-30 23:12:19.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24136): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #2**.

**ProposalListActivity.java**

```
    public class ProposalListActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

        public final static String ASSIGNED_USER_ID = "assignedUserId";

        public static final String PROPOSAL_LIST_TYPE = "proposalListType";

        public final static int ASSIGNED_PROPOSALS = 1;
        /**
         * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the sections. We use a
         * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
         * intensive, it may be best to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
         */
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

        /**
         * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
         */
        ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_proposal_list);
            Log.i("Proposal list activity","Proposal list activity");

            Log.i("sharedpreferences get Response in PP",""+SessionManager.getLoginResponse(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "responseLogin"));
             // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.proposal_list, menu);
            return true;
        }
    /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                if(position == 0) {
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(ProposalListActivity.ASSIGNED_USER_ID, 1);
                    args.putInt(PROPOSAL_LIST_TYPE,ASSIGNED_PROPOSALS);
                    ProposalListFragment frag = new ProposalListFragment();
                    frag.setArguments(args);
                    return frag;
                    }
        }
**ProposalListFragment.java**



     public class ProposalListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<ProposalListItem>>{

        private final static String TAG = ProposalListFragment.class.getName();
        private ProposalListLoader proposalListLoader;
        private ProposalListAdapter proposalListAdapter;
        private int userId;
        NetworkConnection networkConnection;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            networkConnection = new NetworkConnection(getActivity());
            int proposalListType = getArguments().getInt(ProposalListActivity.PROPOSAL_LIST_TYPE);
            switch (proposalListType) {
                case ProposalListActivity.ASSIGNED_PROPOSALS:
                    userId = getArguments().getInt(ProposalListActivity.ASSIGNED_USER_ID);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
          Log.i("net diable",""+networkConnection.isConnectingToInternet());
      getLoaderManager().initLoader(100001, null, this);
         }

        @Override
        public Loader<List<ProposalListItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            proposalListLoader = new ProposalListLoader(userId, getActivity());
            return proposalListLoader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<ProposalListItem>> arg0,List<ProposalListItem> proposals) {
             if(proposals == null)
           {
             Log.i(TAG,"INTERNET DISABLE ....OnLoadFinished of PP list fragment");
            // getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(arg0.getId());
                setListAdapter(proposalListAdapter);
                if(isResumed()) {
                       setListShown(false);
                   } else {
                       setListShownNoAnimation(true);
                   }
           }
           else
           {
            proposalListAdapter = new ProposalListAdapter(getActivity(), proposalListLoader);
            setListAdapter(proposalListAdapter);
            if(isResumed()) {
                   setListShown(true);
               } else {
                   setListShownNoAnimation(true);
               }

           }
    }
    }
```

**ProposalListService.java**
it is bringing data from Service

```
public class ProposalListService {

    private final static ProposalListService INSTANCE = new ProposalListService();
public List<ProposalListItem> getAssignedProposals(int surveyourId) {

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        formData.add("surveyour_id",String.valueOf(surveyourId));

        //Populate the MultiValueMap being serialized and headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, WorkflowRestService
                .getInstance().getRequestHeaders());

        // Perform the HTTP GET request
        ResponseEntity<ProposalListItemHolder> responseEntity = WorkflowRestService.getInstance().getRestTemplate()
                .exchange(WorkflowApp.getServicesURL()+"proposals/getProposals", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ProposalListItemHolder.class);
        Log.i("response Entity",""+responseEntity);
        //convert the array to a list and return it
        ProposalListItemHolder holder = responseEntity.getBody();
        Log.i("response Entity body",""+responseEntity.getBody());
        if ("true".equals(holder.getStatus()))
        {   Log.i("holder.getProposalListItems",""+holder.getProposalListItems());
            return holder.getProposalListItems();
        }
        else
            Log.i("else block of pp",""+holder.getProposalListItems());
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

there is also Adapter class and ListItemHolder class that wraps data while the only problem is it is not showing empty list /data on absence of internet and it crashed and giving

```
**error 01-30 23:12:19.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24136): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #2**
can someone please help me its very weird error that is crashing app.Please help me 
**EDIT added more logcat:**

> 01-30 23:30:55.970: I/internet connection cheking before calling doLogin()(25590): true
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/do login method(25590): login button clickedusername:kongpasswor:kongkong
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/try block login(25590): try block of initialize Loader
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/in loader(25590): login button clickedusername:kongpasswor:kongkong
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/login loader(25590): LoginLoader{422d8f28 id=0}
01-30 23:30:55.970: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.User(25590): starting proposals loader...
01-30 23:30:55.970: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.User(25590): load in background if
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/username(25590): kong
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/password(25590): kongkong
01-30 23:30:55.970: I/apkVersion(25590): 2013-07-10 01:18:26
01-30 23:30:57.295: I/response Entity Login(25590): <200 OK,com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.UserListItemHolder@4233a248,{Server=[nginx/1.4.4], Date=[Thu, 30 Jan 2014 07:37:36 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[close], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1391106656297], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1391106657272]}>
01-30 23:30:57.295: I/response Entity Body Login Function(25590): com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.UserListItemHolder@4233a248
01-30 23:30:57.295: I/LoginListService if condition(25590): Name: kong,Password: f10343d1dc8d44c8935b356aa3f8aae2,First Name: Kongmesssage:Successfully Logged In.status:true
01-30 23:30:57.295: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.User(25590): load in background else
01-30 23:30:57.300: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.model.User(25590): delivering login, size
01-30 23:30:57.300: I/status(25590): Name: kong,Password: f10343d1dc8d44c8935b356aa3f8aae2,First Name: Kong
01-30 23:30:57.580: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25590): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-30 23:31:04.940: I/Proposal list activity(25590): Proposal list activity
01-30 23:31:04.940: I/sharedpreferences get Response in PP(25590): not null
01-30 23:31:04.960: I/net diable(25590): false
01-30 23:31:04.965: D/AbsListView(25590): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-30 23:31:04.965: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.loader.ProposalListLoader(25590): starting proposals loader...
01-30 23:31:04.965: D/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.loader.ProposalListLoader(25590): proposals not found in cache, loading proposals...
01-30 23:31:04.970: I/net diable(25590): false
01-30 23:31:04.970: W/dalvikvm(25590): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416162a0)
01-30 23:31:04.970: D/AbsListView(25590): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-30 23:31:04.970: E/AndroidRuntime(25590): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #3
01-30 23:31:13.300: I/Choreographer(25590): Skipped 491 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

[Formatted the code & logcat properly]

Comment: Can you paste more of the log?

Comment: I too was having same problem then what i did is , To over come this you can check that internet connection is available or not if yes then goto the content and if not just show the alert box .

Comment: please paste your log.

Comment: @InnocentKiller  i cant do becuase every time i need to know whether internet connected or not ....... even on application Resume i will need to check that internet present or not

Comment: @SMR the logcat indicates that app breaks at somepoint of ONLOadFnished of ProposalListFragment.java

Comment: @GregGiacovelli can u please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you're not checking connection availability inside `getAssignedProposals()`.
maybe you should try catching `IOException` in `getAssignedProposals()` (and maybe return an empty list?), so the exception don't get thrown over to the worker thread?